# Django error when trying to migrate models with foreignkeys that don't have null=True or default set

Tags: python, django

I have this model that is a post like on Twitter, that has a creator. I'd ideally like the post to always require a creator_id and if the creator gets deleted then delete the post as well

```
class Post(AbstractBaseModel):
    creator_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_creator_id")
    body = models.CharField(max_length=511)
```

Whenever I try to run 'python manage.py migrate' I get this error

"You are trying to change the nullable field 'creator_id' on cheerpost to non-nullable without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows)."

The options to solve this are are 1) provide a one off default or 2) ignore for now. Neither of these seem to fulfill my constraint that I want to enforce, which is creator_id must exist and is the person who created the post or the entity gets deleted.

I've tried deleting the DB and recreating it from scratch in postgres as well as deleting it using the following query:

TRUNCATE Post;
DELETE FROM Post;

Comment: May you've had a null value before for  ```creator_id```. Please check. What's that ```cheerpost``` ?

Comment: @Ram Django just calls it that cause the app is called cheer so it just calls it cheerpost.

Comment: If you've deleted the DB, that doesn't reflect any changes in django. You have to delete the old migrations too. Delete those old migrations from your app and run create new migrations. That might help.

Comment: @Ram post as answer and I'll give you the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've deleted the DB, just the data and tables from DB are deleted.

That doesn't reflect any changes in Django. All the changes you've made to the fields of your model still exist in migrations. You have to delete the old migrations too.

Delete those old migrations from your app, create new migrations from scratch and apply them.

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Django is asking you to provide a one-off default for any rows you already have in your database, since the field was nullable before the migration. The issue is that Django doesn’t know if there are any rows in the existing database where that column is null, so it needs instructions on what to do if it finds any. You can just provide one and forget about it—it will never be used again after the migration is complete.

Also, you may want to review how the `related_name` parameter works; you’ve got it backwards.

Comment: actually I cleared my table completely and got the error as well as deleted the table and created a totally new one and still got the error. Sorry I should have mentioned that in my post. I'll add it now.

Comment: Django won’t check to see if there are any rows before hand, it just asks for a default no matter what. If the table is empty, you can provide any default and be fine.

Comment: okay, but in future entity creations it'll validate that the attribute isn't null?

Comment: Ram suggested deleting the migrations, but it doesn't sound like from what you're telling me that it'll fix the problem? Unless the issue is truly the previous migrations and what Django expects to be there.